# AEM6 - Image component - I'm not able to render image as background

Tags: aem, sling

I'm using tne sling component /libs/wcm/foundation/components/image.

I need to use the rendering image as css background.

```
<img src="${image.src} /> -> OK: works

<div style="background-image: url('${image.src}')">my text</div> -> KO:  does not work.
```

The result is `<div style="background-image: url('')">my text</div>`

I tried it on Chrome, FF and IE.

Can anyone help me solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
style="background-image:url('${image.src @ context='unsafe'}')"
```

Comment: You should also try context 'uri' instead of 'unsafe'. Works for me in AEM 6.0.

Answer (score 3):

Sightly automatically escapes the values to prevent Cross Site Scripting issues, when do display context is specified. For CSS Strings, use the display context `styleString` so that it encodes characters that would break out of the string.

```
<div style="background-image: url('${image.src @ context='styleString'}')">my text</div>
```

For more information on display context, refer to [Sightly docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/expression-language.html#Display%20Context)

Comment: I read the 'Sigthtly docs' and I tried using @ context = 'styleString'  but does not work (I wondered about it).
Only @ context='unsafe' works fine ...

Comment: Can you please let me know the output after using this? I am sure it works since I am using the same.

Comment: With @ context = 'styleString' :
<div style="background-image: url('\x2Fcontent\x2Fcgm\x2Dsling\x2Dproject\x2Fit\x2Findex\x2Fjcr\x3Acontent\x2Fcontent\x2Fimage.img.png'); height:120px; width:300px ;border: 5px solid red">/content/cgm-sling-project/it/index/_jcr_content/content/image.img.png</div>

With @ context='unsafe':
<div style="background-image: url('/content/cgm-sling-project/it/index/jcr:content/content/image.img.png'); height:120px; width:300px ;border: 5px solid red">/content/cgm-sling-project/it/index/_jcr_content/content/image.img.png</div>

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behaviour. The `/`'s in the image path have been encoded so that it doesn't break the String. The browser would decode it and pick the image correctly. But using `unsafe`, Sightly doesn't perform any kind of validation and allows whatever is passed along.